# Error loading the subtitle file into my mp4 file

Tags: mp4, vlc, srt

I have already did my subtitle file in notepad and saved it as a SRT file but I couldn't load it in my mp4 file through VLC?

```
1
00:09:37.570 --> 00:10:80.570
(car speeding across the road)

2
00:11:70.570 --> 00:13:47.570
(screeching of tires)

3
00:13:70.570 --> 00:15:63.570
(car crash)

4
00:15:70.570 --> 00:20:87.570
(sirens)

5
00:24:77.570 --> 00:25:97.570
(phone buzzes)

6
00:34:43.570 --> 00:39:40.570
Hello?
Yes, it's me.

7
00:41:50.570 --> 00:42:73.570
I'm sorry?

8
00:49:90.570 --> 00:51:30.570
Okay, I'm coming. 

9
00:54:53.570 --> 01:02:10.570
(scribbles of pen)

10
01:05:00.570 --> 01:06:67.570
[car slows down]

11
01:08:00.570 --> 01:10:57.570
(opening and closing of car door)

12
01:11:43.570 --> 01:16:37.570
Can you take me to St. Patrick's Hospital please?
Thank you.

13
01:21:90.570 --> 01:23:20.570
Um, excuse me?

14
01:25:00.570 --> 01:30:80.570
Uh, I'm Penelope and I'm here to see Chris Wardsworth.
He was brought in an hour ago.

15
01:30:97.570 --> 01:33:63.570
Relationship with patient?

16
01:33:67.570 --> 01:35:97.570
He is my brother.

17
01:38:90.570 --> 01:42:80.570
Go to the elevator and ride up to the fourth floor.

18
01:43:50.570 --> 01:44:77.570
Thank you.

19
01:46:97.570 --> 01:55:90.570
(footsteps along the corridor)

20
02:03:00.570 --> 02:04:77.570
Miss Wardsworth.

21
02:05:90.570 --> 02:08:47.570
Yes?
Come here.

22
02:10:90.570 --> 02:18:00.570
Can you see your marks?
You barely pass your exams!!!
Your brother would have passed it with flying colors.

23
02:19:37.570 --> 02:21:97.570
I'm sorry, I'll work harder next time.

24
02:26:15.570 --> 02:28:90.570
Every bad student said that. She is hopeless.

25
02:39:00.570 --> 02:42:18.570
Hey Carrie!
God, Chris, it's good to see you!

26
02:42:53.570 --> 02:49:07.570
Uh, where’s your troublesome sister?
Oh, who knows. Probably in her room sulking about her marks.

27
02:50:80.570 --> 02:54:07.570
She just won't work hard, isn't it?
She's so lazy.

28
02:54:20.570 --> 02:58:30.570
Oh, I’m sorry you have such a dumb sister.
We can’t change that, can we?

29
03:00:70.570 --> 03:02:90.570
Do you really hate me that much?

30
03:04:00.570 --> 03:07:50.570
I’ll take that as a yes… but why?

31
03:10:30.570 --> 03:17:77.570
Is it because you’re jealous?
You are a perfectionist that hates to lose?
That you’d like to be the better one?

32
03:20:43.570 --> 03:27:60.570
Look I might have teased you when we were younger and… 
I really want to apologize for being a jerk.

33
03:28:90.570 --> 03:30:37.570
It's okay.

34
03:30:43.570 --> 03:39:70.570
I know you’re still mad at me. But, from now on we’ll be living together and… 
No matter what happens we’ll get through this together, okay?

35
03:41:50.570 --> 03:45:87.570
I promise I’ll always be by your side.
Thank you.

36
04:30:93.570 --> 04:32:13.570
“I love you more than Spongebob loves Patrick”

37
04:37:13.570 --> 04:38:67.570
How do I solve this?

38
04:40:00.570 --> 04:44:30.570
Hey sis, how’re you doing?
Oh my gosh Chris, you came in the right time!

39
04:40:57.570 --> 04:48:30.570
I’m not doing good but, uh…
Do you know how to find "x"?

40
04:48:70.570 --> 04:51:00.570
Oh, geometry. Let me see.

41
04:59:80.570 --> 05:01:67.570
Yeah, there you go.

42
05:02:05.570 --> 05:03:23.570
Oh my gosh, but how???

43
05:03:70.570 --> 05:07:07.570
Uh… maybe it would be easier if you weren’t that stupid?

44
05:07:63.570 --> 05:12:07.570
[inner voice] Nobody likes you, you know?
Ah… Penelope sorry I don’t mean… I don’t mean--

45
05:13:10.570 --> 05:16:23.570
GET OUT! GET OUT I DON’T WANT TO SEE YOU ANYMORE!!!
Penelope!!!

46
05:16:83.570 --> 05:17:93
GO AWAY!!!

47
05:18:27.570 --> 05:22:13.570
Penelope! I’m sorry, uh… Can I…UGH

48
05:38:00.570 --> 05:38:60.570
Goodbye

49
06:37:20.570 --> 06:40:03.570
Chris? Where is he?

50
06:40:83.570 --> 06:45:50.570
He is currently in surgery. The surgeons are trying their best to save him.

51
06:46:00.570 --> 06:51:63.570
He has broken some of his bones, ribs, and he has lost a lot of blood.

52
06:52:28.570 --> 06:54:17.570
But… he’ll be okay, right?

53
06:55:03.570 --> 06:59:27.570
Well, I can’t be certain about that. I apologize.

54
06:59:80.570 --> 07:07:57.570
However, I think you should better be prepared for the worst.
He wasn’t in a good shape when he was brought in.

55
07:10:83.570 --> 07:14:10.570
I’m sorry. We have tried our very best.

56
07:15:60.570 --> 07:18:53.570
But… he lost too much blood.

57
07:23:13.570 --> 07:25:83.570
…May I have a last look of him?

58
07:32:03.570 --> 07:33:93.570
Hey. Chris...

59
07:34:60.570 --> 07:36:93.570
Hey don’t you do this to me!

60
07:38:53.570 --> 07:40:70.570
Why are you dead...

61
07:42:73.570 --> 07:49:80.570
You are my brother… 
My only friend and my… and my soulmate in the world…

62
07:50:27.570 --> 07:51:90.570
Why are you dead?

63
07:56:13.570 --> 07:58:33.570
Miss, I’m sorry, you have to leave now.

64
07:59:03.570 --> 08:01:33.570
My team will continue the work.

65
08:02:87.570 --> 08:05:53.570
No, I haven’t said my goodbyes yet…

66
08:10:83.570 --> 08:11:97.570
No...

67
08:12:30.570 --> 08:13:47.570
Please, miss.

68
08:15:47.570 --> 08:16:43.570
Let's go.

69
08:23:25.570 --> 08:24:13.570
NO!!!

70
08:27:93.570 --> 08:30:93.570
Miss. are you alright? We have the accused with us now.

71
08:31:23.570 --> 08:35:33.570
He admitted knocking down Mr. … Mr. Wardsworth.

72
08:36:72.570 --> 08:37:10.570
I'm fine.

73
08:37:90.570 --> 08:39:67.570
Miss Wardsworth, this is Mr. Cheng.

74
08:39:69.570 --> 08:42:10.570
Miss Wardsworth, I swear! I didn’t mean to knock him down!

75
08:42:47.570 --> 08:45:90.570
I- I have had some alcohol and I thought I was okay so I drove anyway.

76
08:46:27.570 --> 08:52:67.570
But- but then- he- when I blinked, and my eyesight was blurry and… he was standing there!

77
08:52:70.570 --> 08:56:37.570
And I tried to swerve away from him! But- but it was too late!!

78
08:56:57.570 --> 08:58:90.570
I tried! I really tried!! I’m sorry!!!

79
08:59:50.570 --> 09:00:27.570
I hate you!!!

80
09:26:97.570 --> 09:27:60.570
Dear Chris,

81
09:28:00.570 --> 09:33:87.570
I don’t know if you will be able to read this one day
But I just want to tell you, I’m sorry.

82
09:34:40.570 --> 09:38:03.570
I miss you so much and I can’t stop thinking about us when we were younger.

83
09:38:70.570 --> 09:43:13.570
I was wondering after all these years, do you still feel ashamed of me?

84
09:43:87.570 --> 09:51:67.570
I am so sorry for blocking you out, but I am always late for everything,
And I only just realized how important you are to me.

85
09:52:37.570 --> 09:56:50.570
You are my soulmate, my teacher, my only friend in life.

86
09:56:90.570 --> 10:01:93.570
Without you, I will never be okay. 
I was told to move on, but I can’t.

87
10:02:53.570 --> 10:12:00.570
The guilt of my stupidity and ignorance is eating me alive.
The overwhelming pain assaulted every ounce of my body, especially my heart.

88
10:12:90.570 --> 10:15:40.570
I will never stop regretting for blocking you out.

89
10:16:00.570 --> 10:19:47.570
I miss you. Miss, not missed. Present tense.

90
10:18:83.570 --> 10:21:60.570
Regards, Your sister.
```

I'm stupid, pls help.bgdfstewasrdtfyguhip[awesrdtfy[]\QEAWRS[WEASRFUOIPO[AERSTRDYFUGIUHOIK

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file that you are playing is a video and returns the number of frames per second, vlc will look for a file with exactly the same name as the video but ending with .srt (i.e. myvideo.avi --> myvideo.srt)
The srt file must be in the same directory as the video file.
You can manually load a subtitle file with Subtitle-->Load subtitle file